# android development chart graphs just like analytics app

Tags: android, graph, charts

I am developing an application which will be using some graphs and charts. that been said I saw [Google Analytics app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.giant&hl=en) you can choose view by hourly, daily, weekly and monthly, also set date range, things like that. can anyone give an example or how to start this also what kind of data does it read json xml what format or structure does it read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The are a lot of diffrent jar plugins you can use, from a quick Google search:

1. [Iguana](http://www.infragistics.com/products/android/)
2. [RChart](http://www.java4less.com/charts/chart.php?info=android)
3. [AChartEngine](http://www.achartengine.org/)
4. [GraphView](http://www.jjoe64.com/2011/07/chart-and-graph-library-for-android.html)

And take a look at this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android

Comment: too many choices, don’t know which to use. any recommendations.

Comment: actually I didn't had the time to try them out yet... but why don't you choose the one that you see most suitable for your needs. I think that the Iguana has the best looks and for a project I will have to develop soon I will definitely go with it.